# Drag and sort rows in table using Angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 2 infact angular itself. I have a requirement to drag and drop rows within the table and sort accordingly. Table has 3 columns:

1. attachment link
2. edit dialogue button
3. delete button to delete the row.

for example if I drag row 1 and drop at row 3, row 1 and 3 order will be swapped or sorted. I have my lead wrote a drag and drop directive and drag/drop service which is used in multiple components to drag items from one component to another component. I need to drag and drop and sort the rows within the same table. How to set the scope and target withing the same table? Directive which has OnDragStart, OnDragEnd, OnDragEnter, OnDragOver and OnDragLeave, OnDragDropevents.

After dropping the rows should be sorted so I think i need to have a SortAfterDropmethod to handle this in typesript file. How can I implement this?

here is my html:

this is the tbody where the drag and sort should happen:

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let attachment of form.controls; let i=index" [FormGroupName]="i">
<td>
<ng-container *ngIf="attachment.idValue;else noId">
<a href="investigations/{{investigationid}}/attachments/{{attachment.idValue}}" *ngIf="isPrivate">{{attachment.fileNameValue}}</a>
</td>
<td>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal" (click)="openEditAttachment(editattachment,attachment)"></button>
</td>
</tbody>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Is this `Angular2` with javascript?

Comment: Its Angular2 with typescript

Comment: if you're using a directive written by someone in your team, you'll have to ask the one who wrote this directive. If you can use libs, take a look here: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Comment: He wants me to use his directive and service

Comment: Hi @ChristophLütjen , Can you give me more details on how to use this library because I think this would be more easier to sort the items in the table after dragging instaed of using my lead's dragdrop directive and then write about sorting. PLease let me know more details on this...THank you for your time!

Comment: @Sri pls take a look at the docs. There's much more explained including samples than I could do here.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I referred this for simple sort https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dnd  and added the ng-dnd lib, then added DnD Module in app.module.ts and added below html:

Comment: @ChristophLütjen 
 I am getting Failed to load Resource 404 Not found error..Where do you think I have gone wrong

Comment: <tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let attachment of form.controls; let i=index" [FormGroupName]="i"  dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="form.controls">
<td><ng-container *ngIf="attachment.idValue;else noId">
<a href="investigations/{{investigationid}}/attachments/{{attachment.idValue}}" *ngIf="isPrivate dnd sortable [sortablIndex]="i">{{attachment.fileNameValue}}</a>
</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal" (click)="openEditAttachment(editattachment,attachment)"></button</td></tbody></ng-container>

Comment: @ChristophLütjen When i remove the module reference application is up and running otherwise its throwing 404 failed resource error. PLs suggest where I must have went wrong?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I see the error details as 'cannot find Cannot find module '@angular/core....I installed it using Node.js commend prompt and used npm install ng2-dnd --save and ran it...Is there any way for proper installation of libraries

Comment: This library seems to be not maintained. Really, I'd use cdk. There's a "reordering list" example that seems to do exactly what you're looking for. Then, if you have problems with it, just open a new question here on stackoverflow describing your updated problem. It's impossible for me to help you if I have only infos like "something is not loading..." - we need to see your code.

Comment: @Christoph Lutjen Sure will implement cdk. i figured that ng-dnd is mot compatible with angular 2. Is cdk drabanddrop lub compatible with angular 2?

Comment: The CDK here https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview is "the official" lib for building components. See e.g. the domain which is a sub domain of the angular project itself. Current angular version is 9 but I guess you're not really using angular 2. Note there is angularJS (angular 1) and current angular project (version 2-9) and some people say "angular 2" but mean "angular version 2 and up". You can see which version you're using in your package.json file. Just ensure, you use the CDK package with the same major version number as your angular package.

Comment: Hi @ChristophLütjen The version of angular in package.json is @angular/cli": "1.6.5 "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",  Is that mean I am using 1.6.5 version based on cli or angular 5 based on other versions mentioned?

Comment: That means you're using angular 5. That version is outdated and out of support. You should update your project and expect things are not working as documented for current version. https://angular.io/guide/releases

Comment: Thanks @ChristophLütjen. My lead is upgrading the version to angular 6 but still it may not be compatible to use cdk/dragndrop...I think i have to write a directive for table sorting as there is a directive for drag and drop written.